# Can I set KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY cookie by myself

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect, keycloak

I use KeyCloak with OpenID Connect.

I have an application on the same domain that KeyCloak. This application has a endpoint that takes an authorization code as param, and sets the 'KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY' cookie in the response to enable SSO.

It works, but is it secure to do that?

**EDIT** : My question is about the cookie. I explain the 'why' just to give some context.

**EDIT 2**: For people who want to use this solution, I'm really concerned about the keycloak community... No answer to my question, even with a bounty of 100.

**Why I want to do that:**

I need to set up a SSO between an external website (with it's own auhentication provider, let's call it 'Site A') and a world of applications handled by Keycloak (let's call one of them 'Site K').

As an authenticated user of Site A, if I want to navigate to site K without logging in (i.e. ussing SSO), I need to be logged in on KeyCloak (authorization code flow will do its job).

But, in order to be logged in on KeyCloak, I need to :

1. Get an authorization code
2. Exchange this code for a token which will be added to KeyCloak domain's cookie (KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY)

The 1. is tricky with OIDC but it's possible.

The 2. is not possible with OIDC: there is no endpoint in KeyCloak which can take an authorization code and set a cookie without returning the token in the body.

So, my solution is to add a gateway, on the same domain that KeyCloak, that will get a Token from KeyCloak and add it to KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY cookie... It's tricky but it does work. My question is: is it secure?

If it's not clear: feel free to ask questions!

Comment: Why don't just to directly integrate Site A with Keycloak from Site K? Does Site A has its own database with user identities?

Comment: It has indeed its own database

Answer (score 1):

If it has its own identity database you should consider to integrate this DB to keycloak of site K via [User Storage Provider implementation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/7.0/server_development/index.html#_user-storage-spi) (USP). This way both of your sites will use single Keycloak server for authentication purposes.

There could be issue if identity DB from Site A has user accounts that duplicates in Keycloak of site B, if so your should think about merging (or for example prefer existing users from Keycloak - this is default behavior when user from Keycloak identity DB clashing with user pulled from User Storage Provider Implementation). Also you can create separate realm for USP and use multi-tenancy for your applications.

Comment: You mean then using Keycloak's login page for site A? I can't do that, sadly.

Comment: If you must have different looks of login page in Site A and Site B, you could use separate realm for users from Site A (with custom login theme) or use same realm but ask Keycloak to use separate login themes (you will also have develop them) for applications from site A. Last versions of Keycloak support this feature.

Comment: It's not just about 'looks'. I can't expose Keycloak to Site A: that's my problem ^^ That's why I'm wondering about the 'cookie solution'

Comment: Note that in your current solution Keycloak will be exposed anyway (user will be redirected to it by applications to pass authentication, even if they actually will not see the login page). Also i doubt that you will be able to set KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY cookie from third-party aplication so far this cookie is http-only and should belong to keycloak server domain. Try to check following SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58931035/accepting-a-jwt-token-from-an-external-idp-through-keycloak/58934193#58934193

Comment: Setting the cookie shouldn't be a problem, the 'proxy app' will be on the same domain than keycloak. As said in the question: it works, but I'm wondering if it's secure

Answer (score 0):

You could use user federation, so that any user of site A is also a keycloak user, but there are also keycloak users that are not know to site A. If the standard user fedeation ( LDAP, Kerberos) are not usable for you, you could add a custom user federation SPI

Comment: Thanks, but my question is about the KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY cookie. I've ever thinked about this solution and it's not possible with my case