# Accepting a JWT token from an external IdP through Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I have a setup where Keycloak is acting as an identity broker. There are two Oauth2.0 Identity Providers configured in Keycloak.
A user goes to my app, is forwarded to Keycloak and is presented with two buttons. These buttons can be used to either authenticate with IdP 1 or IdP 2. Once the user is authenticated, keycloak will receive the JWT token and will issue its own JWT token to the client, enriched with claims from the JWT token received from the selected IdP. So far so good.

Now I have the usecase where my app will be embedded in another CRM platform. Let's say this CRM platform uses IdP 1. So a user is able to access the CRM and will authenticate through IdP 1. Then, the user can hit a button and get directed to my app. Of course we don't want the user to authenticate again with the same IdP but now first by going through Keycloak.

My question is, is there a way to let Keycloak use the IdP 1 token the user received when accessing the CRM platform in a way that Keycloak will enrich it and issue a JWT token just as it is done when the user would authenticate through Keycloak?

Answer (score 2):

Consider implementing custom Authenticator that will sign on in Keycloak users that come from CRM. Our goal is to initiate SSO session in Keycloak.

Assume that when user hits button in CRM to got to your app, Keycloak will have access to some data provided by IDP1 that could be useful for identifying which user perform such action. So here we go:

1. User hit button "go to app"
2. User comes to App
3. App redirects user to Keycloak for passing the authentication
4. Your own custom implementation of Keycloak Authenticator will utilize information from IDP1 (you could utilize mentioned JWT token somehow)
5. Now SSO session in established and Keycloak redirects user back to your application
6. ???
7. Profit

Also note that your will have to solve potential problem of session idle synchronization between Keycloak and IDP 1.

[Keycloak development guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_auth_spi)